# How to use color, shape and legend label from different color

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my data frame:

```
> dput(x)
structure(list(cell_type = c("Macrophage_M2", "Monocyte", "Mast_cell", 
"T_cell_CD4+_effector_memory", "T_cell_CD4+_memory", "T_cell_CD8+_naive", 
"B_cell_plasma", "T_cell_CD4+_(non-regulatory)", "T_cell_CD4+_Th2", 
"Endothelial_cell", "T_cell_NK", "T_cell_regulatory_(Tregs)", 
"Cancer_associated_fibroblast", "T_cell_CD4+_central_memory", 
"Hematopoietic_stem_cell", "T_cell_regulatory_(Tregs)", "Hematopoietic_stem_cell", 
"Common_myeloid_progenitor", "Endothelial_cell", "Macrophage_M2"
), cluster = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), vt_score = c(0.620725205988837, 
0.565049819839983, 0.555015252291001, 0.529856563905404, 0.467454576797864, 
0.434671831438467, 0.367378221155799, 0.357576774722313, 0.305798026454146, 
0.222533326094146, 0.457134190027398, 0.447470659870985, 0.447033729409117, 
0.374612139728217, 0.347672664499527, 0.319135092044291, 0.172082683316721, 
0.116551044539405, 0.0763883445051204, 0.0268403599993589), id_col = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L), colors = c("#0D0887FF", "#7E03A8FF", "#CC4678FF", 
"#F89441FF", "#F0F921FF", "#0D0887FF", "#7E03A8FF", "#CC4678FF", 
"#F89441FF", "#F0F921FF", "#0D0887FF", "#7E03A8FF", "#CC4678FF", 
"#F89441FF", "#F0F921FF", "#0D0887FF", "#7E03A8FF", "#CC4678FF", 
"#F89441FF", "#F0F921FF"), shapes = c(16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

First 10 lines for clarity:

```
> head(x, n =10)
                      cell_type cluster  vt_score id_col    colors shapes
1                 Macrophage_M2       1 0.6207252      1 #0D0887FF     16
2                      Monocyte       1 0.5650498      2 #7E03A8FF     16
3                     Mast_cell       1 0.5550153      3 #CC4678FF     16
4   T_cell_CD4+_effector_memory       1 0.5298566      4 #F89441FF     16
5            T_cell_CD4+_memory       1 0.4674546      5 #F0F921FF     16
6             T_cell_CD8+_naive       2 0.4346718      1 #0D0887FF     17
7                 B_cell_plasma       2 0.3673782      2 #7E03A8FF     17
8  T_cell_CD4+_(non-regulatory)       2 0.3575768      3 #CC4678FF     17
9               T_cell_CD4+_Th2       2 0.3057980      4 #F89441FF     17
10             Endothelial_cell       2 0.2225333      5 #F0F921FF     17
```

So here, there are 4 clusters and there is a shape (i.e. shapes column) associated with each cluster. For each cluster, there are 5 `cell_types` values and a color associated with each cell_type value  (i.e. colors column). I want to color and shape using the `colors` and `shapes` columns but want to show the actual `cell_type` as labels in the legend. I have tried the below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
ggplot(data = x, aes(x = cluster, y = vt_score, 
                     color = cell_type, shape = cell_type)) +
  geom_point(size = 5, alpha =  0.8) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = x$cell_type, 
                     values = x$colors) +
  scale_shape_manual(labels = x$cell_type, 
                     values = x$shapes)
```

What I get is this which is incorrect (colors, shapes and cell_types don't seem to match)

[image]

Update:

I used limits based on @aosmith's suggestion below and it worked:

```
# add cell_type and cluster combination for duplicates
x$cell_type_lab <- paste0(x$cell_type,'_',x$cluster)

# use limits, labels (for legend) and values (colors/shapes) 
ggplot(data = x, aes(x = cluster, y = vt_score, 
                     color = cell_type_lab, shape = cell_type_lab)) +
  theme_bw() + theme_Publication2() +
  geom_point(size = 10, alpha =  0.7, position=position_dodge(width=0.05)) +
  scale_color_manual(limits = x$cell_type_lab,
                     labels = x$cell_type,
                     values = x$colors) +
  scale_shape_manual(limits = x$cell_type_lab, 
                     labels = x$cell_type,
                     values = x$shapes)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `limits` or `breaks`, not `labels`?

Comment: @aosmith I think that might work, I am trying will update soon. Thanks!!

Comment: @aosmith can you add this as an answer and I'll accept it, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the colors and legend key in the correct order, use the `cell_type` vector from the dataset as the `limits` along with passing the colors from the dataset to `values`.  Then if you need to change the labels as well as the legend order you can pass a vector of labels to `labels` (in the same order as the other two vectors).

```
ggplot(data = x, aes(x = cluster, y = vt_score, 
                    color = cell_type)) +
     geom_point(size = 5, alpha =  0.8) +
     scale_color_manual(limits = x$cell_type,
                        values = x$colors)
```

[image]